# how to access chrome net-internals from the chrome extension code

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internals

is it possible to access, invoke and see the results of operations in chrome://net-internals/ WITH and from the extension code that I am trying to write/build?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

The closest analog is the [WebRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html), which gives you access to various bits and pieces of the network requests going back and forth between Chrome and the server. That doesn't, however, give you access to some of the even lower-level details that you see in `net-internals`.

What exactly would you like extensions to have access to? I'd suggest formulating a clear use-case, and filing a feature request: http://new.crbug.com/ as your best bet.